# Finding the minimum value of an array subject to an index of another array and values from another one

Tags: python, arrays, minimum

I have a square array called `dist` of certain size `n x n`, a vector called `particion`of size `m<n` with indices from `0` to `n`, and another one called `incidencia` of size `m`. Everything is stored using NumPy.

What I want to find is the minimal value of `dist` subject to two conditions and catch the argument as a vector. This is a rough code from C++ translated into python:

```
num = len(particion)
a = [100] * 2
mini = dist_max
for i in range(num):
    pi = particion[i]
    for j in range(num):
        pj = particion[j]
        if (dist[pi,pj] <= mini) & ((incidencia[i] < 2) & (incidencia[j] < 2)):
            mini = dist[pi][pj]
            a[0] = i
            a[1] = j
```

I feel that this is not the best way to find the minimum since this function takes too much time to compute, even in C++. Is there a better way? A more "python-eske" way?

Comment: Can you use NumPy?

Comment: This would be a perfect use case for heap sort. Sort in O(nlogn), extract min in O(1)

Comment: Yes @rayryeng, I can use NumPy, actually the arrays are stored using NumPy.

Comment: How would I use heap sort @rpg711 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the range of your actual data, so I've generated some random data.

```
from random import randrange

m, n = 100, 200

dist = [[i+j for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
part = [randrange(n) for k in range(m)]
inci = [randrange(9) for k in range(m)]

# keep only items in `part` where corresponding `inci` value < 2
part = [p for p,i in zip(part, inci) if i < 2]

# check dist for all couples in `part` and extract minimal value
d = min(dist[pi][pj] for pi in part for pj in part)
```

This code gives only the minimal distance. If you also need the indices where the min is reached, it is better to switch to `numpy` and use the `argmin` function it provides.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add that all the arrays were stored using `numpy`. I have added that on my question. By the way, the actual data is a matrix of 822 cells, and `m` is around `60` or something. This search is part of a loop that then finds the next min after some other functions take place and so on.
I do need the indices where the min is reached, that is why I store them in `a`.